# Can't get FastNoise to work for grass patches

Tags: c++, sfml, noise

I have been trying to implement noise based grass patches all day. Before I just had it pick random tiles, but they looked bad because they weren't in patches.

```
FastNoise GrassNoise;
for (int x = 0; x < MapSizeX; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < MapSizeY; y++) {
        if (GrassNoise.GetValue(Map[x][y].Sprite.getPosition().x, Map[x][y].Sprite.getPosition().y) > 0.5) {
            Map[x][y].Sprite.setTexture(*Grass);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm just not generating the Noise correctly. With that code, all of the tiles get turned grass. I'm looking for just a few patches.

github.com/Auburns/FastNoise

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you should do something in the else branch to set it to another texture, or is it pre-initialized? please show the code :) Also, where is the code for `FastNoise` ? Are you using this class correctly?

Comment: https://github.com/Auburns/FastNoise

Comment: It still is all grass even if I have an else block which sets the tex to dirt. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, that's why I came here.

Comment: Are you sure `Map[x][y].Sprite.getPosition().x`and `Map[x][y].Sprite.getPosition().y` are integers? if they are floating points between 0 and 1 that would explain it. Or maybe you need to set the noise type, like in the tutorial : https://github.com/Auburns/FastNoise/wiki

Comment: GrassNoise.SetNoiseType(FastNoise::SimplexFractal);
 GrassNoise.SetSeed((rand() % 100000));
 GrassNoise.SetFrequency(0.15);

Comment: GrassHeightMap[x][y] = GrassNoise.GetValue(x, y);

Comment: if (GrassHeightMap[x][y] > 0.5) { /* generate grass */ }

Comment: I think you can write an answer yourself, to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the problem was that the arguments passed to `GrassNoise.GetValue` were floating points in the [0,1] range, whereas the function expects integers.